# how to access hiddenfield value in different page?

Tags: javascript, c#, user-controls

is it possible to access hiddenfield value in one usercontrol(.ascx file) to another usercontrol(.ascx file)?If yes,then how to pass hidden field value from one usercontol to another.
this is hiddenfield which is storing  image url

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGoogleProfilePic" runat="server" />
```

in javscript like this

`imageurlHTML = "<img src='" + resp['image']['url'] + "' />";
            hdnGoogleProfilePic = imageurlHTML;`

now i have to send this hiddenfield value to other usercontrol in order to display image in that usercontrol.
can you help me?

Comment: Can't you solve it serverside ?

Comment: it will be preferable to store image  on client side

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send it using ajax and jquery:

```
$.ajax(
    url: "path/to/your/ctrl",
    data: {value: yourElement}
}).done(function() {
 ....
});
```

Comment: i want to store it on client side.

Comment: In this case you can easy get it by element id using jquery: $('#hdnGoogleProfilePic') or without it: document.getElementById('hdnGoogleProfilePic').

Comment: for same usercontrol it will work fine,but on other usercontrol(which will load after page postback)it wont work.

Comment: Put the selection of an element on load callback.

Answer (score 0):

In UserControl#1 you can add that value to a Session variable and in UserControl#2 you can bind it/read it to a "runat=server" input element e.g. :

Assuming you have this in your UC#1:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGoogleProfilePic1" runat="server" value="Something" />
```

And assuming you need the value of hdnGoogleProfilePic1 in UC2.

In UC#1 page in an event handler (an event that you know the value has been sent by the client to the server e.g. a button click), add this:

```
Session["myHiddenField"] = hdnGoogleProfilePic1.Value;
```

In UC2 add this method:

```
public String GetHiddenFieldVal(){
  if (Session["myHiddenField"]){
    return ((String)(Session["myHiddenField"]));
  }
  return "";
}
```

Then in UC2, in your markup add this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGoogleProfilePic2" runat="server" value="<%# GetHiddenFieldVal()%>" />
```

So you are using hdnGoogleProfilePic1 which is in UC1 in another hidden field in UC2.

Hope it helps.